# scikit-learn classification using doc2vec representation

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification, doc2vec

I want to classify text documents using doc2vec representation and scikit-learn models.

My problem is that I'm lost on how to get started. can someone explain the general steps usually taken to use doc2vec with scikit-learn?

Answer (score 9):

There is a great tutorial [here](http://linanqiu.github.io/2015/10/07/word2vec-sentiment/) for a binary classification with scikit-learn + doc2vec. In short:

- Using `gensim` to train/load your doc2vec model.
- Input text will be converted to a fixed dimension vector of floats (the same dimension as your embedding). These are the actual input features.
- Now feel free to use any classifier in `scikit-learn`.